# How to set Browser caching and expires headers via .htacess

Tags: browser-cache, expires-header

Ive got a centOS lamp server running a static html, css, js site. Google's page speed tool suggested i "Leverage browser caching" (as this may be a google seo ranking factor we want to implement it). Is this something that can be done via the .htaccess file of my site ?

Ive set this up in the past but only via a wordpress plugin so it was pretty much one click.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this to the top of your htaccess-file:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Comment: thanks ill give that a shot, just a thought, like most sites we've got allot of external JS requests analytics, hosted scripts ect. If we set `ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"` would that only count for items on our server and not count against external scripts ?

Comment: Yes, external files won't be effected by mod_expires :/